# Encrypting HTTP Post Data

Tags: encryption, http

How can I encrypt HTTP POST data using symmetric encryption? 
I know that you can use HTTPS and make your HTTP run over TLS, but is there a way to do that without using HTTPS and how?

Comment: TLS _does_ use symmetric encryption. Why do you want to avoid TLS?

Comment: TLS uses symmetric encryption to encrypt the data, including POST data. TLS uses asymmetric encryption only to establish a symmetric key shared among the client and the server.

Comment: If you want to know how to code your own encryption over HTTP and not HTTPS, that's more of a coding question. You just encrypt the application data, but you need the encryption process on both sides. Also, you will need to sort out the problem of passing the symmetric key. To do that, you could use asymmetric encryption, but then you would need to code that into your application, too. Or, you could use TLS that has had this all sorted out for 23 years.

Comment: Franky, if you want to do all this without TLS, I'd still recommend that you read  about TLS so you can implement a known good method to your application-level encryption. But ***how*** to do that is a coding question.